# Javascript foreach issue === not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have two arrays and need to find index from one and get the element on the other array index.
For some reason everything looks good to me but method still returns undefined but i'm expecting Station_2 as index is 2 which is passed. it returns undefined

```
 function FindBestStation(x,choosenItem,y)
    {
        x.forEach(
        function(tempItem)
        {
            if(tempItem===choosenItem)
            {
                return y[tempItem-1];
            }

        });
    }
    var x=[1,2,3,4, 10];
    var y=['Station_1','Station_2','Station_3','Station_4','Station_10'];
    var choosenItem=2;//another algorithm finds this value

    var choosenElement=FindBestStation(x,choosenItem,y);
    console.log(choosenElement);
```

Comment: tempItem is used as index in forEach loop which may not be available always in the array variable `x`

Comment: I see the presentation of a problem but no real question; what exactly is it you are asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript foreach method doesn't break so its not === issue its return statement on foreach is the issue.

I have modified the code this should work
[Reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
function FindBestStation(x,choosenItem,y)
{
    var elementFound;
    x.forEach(
    function(tempItem)
    {

        if(tempItem===choosenItem)
        {
            elementFound= y[tempItem-1];
            return;

        }

    });
    return elementFound;
}

var x=[1,2,3,4, 10];

var y=['Station_1','Station_2','Station_3','Station_4','Station_10'];

var choosenItem=2;//another algorithm finds this value

var choosenElement=FindBestStation(x,choosenItem,y);
console.log(choosenElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement is inside your `.forEach()` callback. It therefore really won't do anything useful. The "FindBestStation" function has no `return` statement at all, so it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

callback is invoked with three arguments:

the element value

the element index

the array being traversed

You could do something like this:

```js
    function FindBestStation(x,choosenItem,y)
    {
        x.forEach(
        function(tempItem,index,array)
        {
            if(tempItem===choosenItem)
            {
                choosenElement = y[index];
            }

        });
    }
    var x=[1,2,3,4, 10];
    var y=['Station_1','Station_2','Station_3','Station_4','Station_10'];
    var choosenItem=2;//another algorithm finds this value

    var choosenElement;
    FindBestStation(x,choosenItem,y);
    console.log(choosenElement);
```